# UFT - How to run 2 test set using ALM scheduler?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, alm

We are using UFT for automation and executing our scripts through ALM scheduler. We are able to execute the one test set through ALM scheduler. Is it possible to execute 2 test set [image]through ALM scheduler?. 
Refer attached screen shot for more details.
We want to execute the test set '14Nov_Run1' after the complete execution of '13Dec_Amend' test set.

Answer (score 0):

You can Ctrl-click multiple tests if you hover on the first column, then click "run".

Be aware the execution is parallel only if it is two distinct target machines, and if the execution dependencies allow this.